# Cloned SSD and it appears my file system is screwy

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, mbr

I used dd to clone my 160GB SSD to a 500GB SSD. It boots and runs fine but things just aren't quite right. I'm not an advanced Linux user and don't want to screw anything up so here are the clues:

*1. I tried to install gparted through the Software Center and I got the following error: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend".*

I had just booted and this was the first thing I did. I was able to install gparted via apt-get so it's not a big deal but I thought it might be relevant.

*2. fdisk -l output: (Note I removed all of the loop bits -- they seem unrelated)*

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 102402047 102400000  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102404094 312580095 210176002 100.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       102404096 200060345  97656250  46.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       296046592 312580095  16533504   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

**Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.**

*3. There's a block of unallocated space in the middle of my drive: (gparted output:).*

[image]

This was present before I cloned the SSD but I'm not sure how it got there (probably inattention) but I'd like to move it if it won't screw everything up. If not I'll just make the Ubuntu partition 100GB I suppose.

*4. My Windows partition no longer shows up in the file manager.*

This would be rather nice and I would hope that once I make a partition out of the unallocated space that that will show up. That's rather important.

I'm wondering if I should just keep my Windows partition, delete the other partitions, and start over with Ubuntu. I'd like to know what went wrong for the sake of learning but I need this thing up and running reliably ASAP.

Comment: With ubuntu partition almost full, would delete unallocated and expand.  Need to use a live ubuntu installer USB.  Might be better to start over, Windows partition needs to be bigger also.  Can you boot into Windows itself?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I figured out the above somehow (it's been a while, sorry) and forgot that I had posted here. I tried to move some stuff around and the file system got so screwed up that I decided it was best to back up and start over. Thank you!